# Passing objects from Components to services

Tags: angular

I want to pass the data from a component in the URL of a service. Is this possible.

Currently in my `console.log(hotel_id);` I am getting two values. I want to pass those in my service.

Here's my component:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GetHotelService } from '../../services/gethotel/getHotel.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'selectHotel',
    templateUrl: 'selectHotel.component.html',
    providers: [GetHotelService]
})
export class selectHotelComponent  {
    hotelData: HotelData[];
    hotel: string;

    constructor(private getHotelService: GetHotelService){

        this.getHotelService.getHotel().subscribe(hotelData => {
            this.hotelData = hotelData.data;
            for (let e of hotelData.data){
                var hotel_id = e.hotel_id;
                console.log(hotel_id);
            }
        })

    }
}

interface HotelData {
    hotel_name: string,
    hotel_id: number
}
```

Instead of `hotel_id = 40` I want to pass the values from there:

Here's the service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
    export class GetRoomService {
        constructor(private http: Http){
        }

        getRoom(){
            return this.http.get('url&hotel_id=40')
                .map(res => res.json());
        }
    }
```

Also in my select tags I am not able to set the first value as selected.
And `x.hotel_id` will give me the ID. Will I be able to pass it from here instead?

```ts
<div>
    <select name="hotel">
        <option *ngFor = "let x of hotelData" [value] = "x.hotel_name">{{x.hotel_name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here's the getHotelService:

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
    export class GetHotelService {
        constructor(private http: Http){
        }

        getHotel(request:any){
        const body=JSON.stringify(request);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'value' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post('' , body, options).map(res => res.json());

        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a parameter to `getRoom` and call it like that? `getRoom(hotel_id)` so call it like `this.getRoomService.getRoom(40)`

Comment: Are you sure data is passed correctly both to your server and on the way back to client app?

Comment: @borkovski Yes when I pass `40` in `hotel_id=`. It gives me the same two objects in the console with the data. But when I pass in the parameters as in the answer by Pankaj it gives me those two objects again but without the data in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getRoom` method to accept parameters

```
getRoom(hotel_id){
    return this.http.get(`url&hotel_id=${hotel_id}`)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And then pass parameter from `selectHotelComponent`

```
var hotel_id = e.hotel_id;
this.getHotelService.getRoom(hotel_id).subscribe(
   (data) => console.log(data)
);
```

Comment: When I use `this.getRoom` it gives me an error in console `_this.getRoom` is not a function and when I use `this.getRoomService.getRoom` then I gives me two objects. But there is no data in them. The console gives `data: Array(0)`

Comment: I want it when I select an option in the dropdown then the data changes accordingly.  But show the first option's data by default

Comment: @SLASH you could pass `hotelData.data[0].hotel_id` to `getRoom` method

Comment: My `getHotelService` doesn't have the `getRoom` method. It's in my `getRoomService`. I'll add my getHotel service in the question too.

Comment: I figured that out. Just saw that you have used `backticks` instead of `quotes`. Now it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should take a look at promises. This way you'll be able to use data when it's downloaded: http://learnangular2.com/es6/promises

```
getRoom(hotel_id:number):Promise<Room[]> {
  this.http.get('<correct-url>').toPromise().then((response) => {
    return response.json() as Room[];
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error fetching rooms', ex);
  });
}
```

I'm only guessing if you'll recieve `Room` object and if it's going to be an array or not. What I'm trying to point out is that maybe the only problem is that you're not waiting for data to come back and return it.

Comment: Thank you. I am gonna try this

Comment: Have you tried the code you've posted? This will obviously throw `then is not a function` - because http.get returns an observable. A2 uses observables inherently. There are good use cases for promises in A2, but using promises because the one is not comfortable enough with observables is not a valid excuse.

Comment: @estus You're right, I forgot to add `toPromise()` to convert observable returned from `get()`. I find using `Promise` more comfortable and easier and that IS a valid excuse.

Comment: It worked after I used `backticks` in the get method instead of `quotes`